# Constructing a Linear Map and Extending by Linearity

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working on this problem to better understand the concept of extending by linearity, but I haven't been able to make any headway.

Let $(v_1,..., v_n)$ be a basis for $V$ and let $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb F^n$. Prove that there is a unique linear map $T:V \rightarrow \mathbb F^n$ such that $T v_j = a_j$ for each $j$.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The info you've given is how $V \xrightarrow{T} \mathbb F^n$ acts on basis vectors of $V$, which is exactly what we tabulate in the matrix of a linear transformation! If we write down the vectors $a_1, \dots, a_n$ as column vectors $$
\begin{bmatrix} \vert \\ \mbox{mat}(a_1) \\ \vert\end{bmatrix}, \dots, \begin{bmatrix} \vert \\ \mbox{mat}(a_n) \\ \vert \end{bmatrix}
$$
with respect to some basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of $\mathbb F^n$, then we have
$$
\mbox{mat}(T) = \begin{matrix}
 & v_1 & \cdots & v_n \\
\begin{matrix} e_1 \\ \vdots \\ e_n \end{matrix} & \left[ \begin{matrix} \vert \\ \mbox{mat}(a_1) \\ \vert \end{matrix} \right. & \cdots & \left. \begin{matrix} \vert \\ \mbox{mat}(a_n) \\ \vert \end{matrix} \right],
\end{matrix} 
$$
Because there's a one-to-one correspondence between matrices and linear maps, and we've found a matrix $\mbox{mat}(T)$ such that $\mbox{mat}(T) \cdot \mbox{mat}( v_j ) = \mbox{mat}(a_j)$, we have a linear map such that $T v_j = a_j$.

To see that $T$ is unique, suppose that $S : V \to \mathbb F^n$ is another linear map with $S v_j = a_j$. Then $Tv_j = a_j$ and $S v_j = a_j$, and subtracting gives us $(T - S) v_j = 0$. This holds for *all* basis vectors $v_j$, hence $T - S$ is the zero map, i.e., $T = S$.